# textures rendered as color boxes

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xcode7, port, arm64

I have to upgrade a 32 bit iPhone/iPad app to 64 bit using Xcode7.
This app is old style OpenGL (maybe 2009?) and the code is spaghetti (is a win32 port) so I have no idea how exactly works.
What I know is in 32 bit the textures look ok, but when I change to 64 bit all the textures are rendered as color boxes. Please take a look at the images.
Everything in the app is hardcoded textures including the text (some kind of bmp fonts).
Do you guys have a clue about what can be causing this problem?

[image]

Comment: I recommend you use xcode's opengl frame capture tool and you add checks for opengl errors after every opengl call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the source of evil.
The program is reading bmp's the old school way, so some bmp long data types are 4 bytes in 32 bit but in 64 bit mode are 8 bytes!!!!!!

So I changed long type to int32_t [Look at this debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKwQB.png)